# Change status of "view only" contact in Google Contacts

Tags: google-contacts

I have Nexus 5x running Android 8.1 Oreo with Google Contacts 3.2.5.222172751. I had a friend's name misspelled in my contact list and wanted to fix it. Ordinarily (and on all my other contacts), there is a blue edit button in the bottom right of the interface that displays contact info, but for this contact, it's missing.

When I open the contact from the Google search bar (Google app), it shows the words "read-only" at the top.  I think I created the contact in the normal way (rather than through another app). Yes, I could delete the contact and create a new one. That would be quite easy, but that's not the answer I'm looking for.

How do I fix the contact settings? Or if somehow not possible, what in the world? What is a "view only" contact?

Comment: I am guessing that this contact was created through some app (hangouts or something else) though you think it is not the case. Hence probably not editable. Go to contacts on web and check if that contact is there. If not, it confirms guess

Comment: This was so many years ago. I wonder if you ever figured this out. I have 1000s of contacts that are read only. It looks like I may have to delete my whole entire address book which will be a nightmare.

Thanks, T

PS: Sorry, I didn't suggest I have an answer. I myself am looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem recently; here's the answer I found worked immediately.

Use the phone app. Like, the one you use to make phone calls.

Google Contacts apparently doesn't look at where the contact comes from, only that it didn't create it. And then just gives up.

But lo and behold, clicking the big green phone button and searching for that contact not only revealed two accounts with the same name (associated with another app), but both were easily and quickly deleted.

And now I have the right contact name in Google Voice! Miracles.